# Decode JWT using Appsync Resolver Mapping Template

Tags: aws-appsync

I have stored  a custom claim the IdToken and I send the whole token into the graphql interface using a custom header called "customs". How can I decode it to an object in a resolver and get the value of the claim?

I have tried this:

```
#set($myClaim=$context.request.headers.get('customs').myClaim)
```

I didn't expect this code to work, because the header is encoded, but I saw it in an example and I post it here so you can get a picture of what I am trying to do.